# How to display a notification in worklight when returning to the foreground?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am using push notification in worklight 6.2 in one of my apps.

I have a issue regarding receiving of notification. i receive notification when i am in the application .

When i close my app or made my app go background, i receive notification in the status bar and when i click on that,its taking me to the app ask for the authentication which is provided in the app and then goes to the inbox where all the messages are listed the new message is displayed .

But when i receive the notification when my apps is in background and see the notification in status bar and without clicking that notification if i opened the application and see the inbox page ,the message is not displayed because the function which will be executed when receiving notification is not called.

I need to give solution to avoid this. Is there any way or option to display the notification which is received when the app is in background and when the app is opened without opening the notification in status bar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a the [Cordova `resume` event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume), from which you will call the `pushNotificationReceived()` function as the callback function.

`document.addEventListener("resume", pushNotificationReceived, false);`

The basic premise is that if a notification was received while you were in the background, then once returning to the foreground the above should executed and the notification will be displayed.

Again, this is just the basic premise and you'll probably need to modify the `pushNotificationReceived()` implementation to account for what happens when you get back to the foreground but there are no notification (you could implement some logic to check that...) and various other scenarios, as you encounter them.

Comment: yes usually the function will be having the messages.but in this way how to get the latest notification that came.The usual function will parameter like this pushNotificationReceived(props, payload).I want the props and payload to be used .How to get the messages and payloads in the method u have mentioned.

Comment: The JS API for push notifications is not robust enough to give you control over that; there is a queue and if there is more than 1 messages you will get all of the messages that were not yet processed.

Comment: Your other option is to implement push notifications support using native code in your hybrid app. More on that in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358191/how-to-tell-app-was-started-by-tapping-push-message-notification/'

Comment: in first method how to process the message queue.because you are calling a function that will not the message ,how to get the the queue.

Comment: As I wrote, you do not have control over the queue when using the JS API (feel free to submit a feature request for Worklight product designers to evaluate it); You will need to investigate using my second suggestion of using native push API in your Hybrid application.

Comment: After you bring the app to foreground, you can tap the notification in the status bar so that it will appear in your inbox. Is it like you want the pushNotificationReceived callback to be called (so that inbox gets updated) when the app is brought to the foreground without tapping the notification?

Comment: What? Now you're confusing me. India? Norway? Are you in fact saying that you do get the pop-up when the application is brought to the foreground? and how is that related to processing the multiple notifications? Please, make sense of this.

Comment: Please do not ask other questions in this question. If you have a new question, open a new question and provide all logs from devices in india and in norway. Do not use this question for it.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have a doubt when my app is trying to register with the  push notification , it is saying that the current version 4.4 dosnt support notification.